# How can I remove the Timer lever on a Pentax ME Super?

Tags: repair, pentax, maintenance, old-cameras

I'd like to carefully remove the **Timer lever** on my **Pentax ME Super** to give it a new skin.

[image]

I have not been able to find help online.

Someone suggested I use very small pliers, but that seems improbable, I want to make sure I use the right tool and don't mess with a perfectly fine camera just to replace the leather.

EDIT: Maybe for [something like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00J5F73GA) but I'd want the width of the tool to not hit the lens part or I wouldn't be able to unscrew

Comment: I am not affiliated, but perhaps if you contact someone like cameraleather.com, they can help

Answer (score 3):

Here you go...

http://www.pickmycamera.net/service-pentax-mesuper/

According to the article they have a special tool to remove the timer lever

Comment: They have an "improvised tool" but they do not give any details on it... I think they are called "Spanner" screwdrivers but I cannot find a list or the right one https://bit.ly/2O4czwb

Comment: https://www.micro-tools.com/collections/spanner-wrenches.   This looks like what I would get to handle that problem.

Comment: Just as with some lenses, calipers (please don't use your best calipers for that... if you only have good calipers, get a junk pair at a yard sale or something!) can sometimes be pressed into service for that kind of task - they already have two pointy ends at variable distance :)

Comment: I am afraid that calipers would damage the screw's sockets/holes because of the calipers shape, which is what I am trying to avoid since this is a cosmetic job.

Comment: I ended up realizing the problem was to unscrew clockwise... and was able to do it.